# Web.API Deploy URLs not working?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, web-deployment

In my Web.API project, for development in the web settings I use the 'Project Url:' of `http://localhost/reporter` on my local IIS web server.  There are pages that are served up from this site using asp.net mvc4 with javascript calls that post to urls like 'api/getdata/'.

For some reason, these have stopped working- for example, I would make a jQuery post to 'api/getdata' and the full URL was `http://localhost/reporter/api/getdata` which was correct.  And life was good.

But now something has changed- same jQuery post, nothing else in code different that I'm aware of, but my full URL's are now `http://localhost/api/getdata` - I lost that 'reporter' part.  I think something may have happened when I deployed this to another internal server- it worked great locally- then I deployed and noticed it didn't work on the new server.  And then I discovered that I wasn't working locally anymore.

I've double checked and my project config seems to be the same as it was before...?

I'm sure I broke something, but I have no idea what.  Thoughts?

Comment: did you use virtual directory for development? whatever, you should post with url: `/api/getdata` rather than using absolute URL

Comment: I did use the virtual directory... but doesnt my web.api app live at `http://localhost/reporter`?  And so calls -should- be `http://localhost/reporter/api/getdata`?  I dont post to absolute urls, my jQuery post is exactly like 'url: "api/getdata"'

Comment: So stop using Vritual directory, your problem just relates to IIS

Comment: What do you mean?  I have a 'Create Virtual Directory' option in web settings, no remove.  How do you stop using virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend using a tool such as Fiddler or your web browser's development tools to do a network trace and see what the failed request is.

The most likely culprit seems to me to be that the virtual directory is different, or perhaps the browser's URL is different, and that causes the relative path to be resolved incorrectly. Relative paths are generally a very bad thing to use on the client because the client often doesn't know relative to *what* the URL is.

I recommend adding just a bit of client side code like this:

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

And that will declare a JavaScript variable that contains the "root" of the app. Then, elsewhere in the page, you can have code that uses the base URL and appends the rest of the relative path:

```
<script>
    $.ajax(...., baseUrl + "api/getdata", ...);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am using fiddler, and the failed url is as I have described.  I access the index page via `http://localhost/reporter` and while the scripts in that page used to post to `http://localhost/reporter/api/getdata` they now post to `http://localhost/api/getdata`.  I can easily work around this, but I want to know what changed- and why the page no longer has the correct base URL by default.

Comment: @Nicros, indeed, that might be the case, but I would argue that the code is still incorrect because it is making invalid assumptions. I do strongly recommend mapping the base path in the server code and then using that for the client code. It is possible that there are other problems related to the virtual directory being different as well.

Comment: I think that's fair.  I was thinking when I started this (since it worked) that using the relative url was just fine- but clearly that's not the case :) It makes sense to map that base path in as well.